# Woocommerce Booking | Add to Cart customization

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed Woocommerce Bookings plugin with Woocommerce Plugin. I have also created a custom plugin in which i want to add the booking to the cart at the end for default way of checkout process. How can it be possible to add my bookable product to add to the cart and then checkout with the payment gateway used?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom product type having it's own custom fields for this.
Paste the below code in your functions.php, try to create a product there will be another product type called Booking Product. you may get some idea.

```
// add a product type
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'wdm_add_custom_product_type' );
function wdm_add_custom_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'booking_product' ] = __( 'Booking Product' );
    return $types;
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wdm_create_custom_product_type' );
function wdm_create_custom_product_type(){
     // declare the product class
     class WC_Product_Wdm extends WC_Product{
        public function __construct( $product ) {
           $this->product_type = 'booking_product';
           parent::__construct( $product );
           // add additional functions here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have installed Woocommerce Bookings plugin which adds product as "Booking Product" but i want to add that bookable product to cart using default woocommerce way. Please suggest

Comment: @Dev I have not used that plugin, but I can tell you how you can add a product to cart manually , you can do this using `WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) `after that you can send the required fields to your payment gateway lets take paypal, so you need send the require html data you can take the reference from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU